# ARM64 Code Injection on Apple M1 crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, apple-m1, code-injection, arm64, dll-injection

I have the following code to inject a payload into a process.
The payload will then call `dlopen` to load a dll from disk.

When I inject the payload into my own process `getpid()`, it works fine, I can see the dll loads and prints correctly.

When I inject it into another process, I get:

```
0x104cc0030: ldr x0, [x29, #0x18]

Thread 2: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10005e85c)
```

This `ldr x0, [x29, #0x18]` is when the code does `_pthread_set_self(thread_id);`.
It seems whenever any code tries to read `thread_id`, it gives a bad access error.
I don't see how though because my stack is `read/write` and my code is `read/execute`.

The code for injecting is as follows:

```
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>

class Injector
{
public:
    static bool Inject(std::string module_path, std::int32_t pid, void* bootstrap) noexcept;
};


// Implementation

#if defined(__APPLE__)
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_vm.h>
#include <mach-o/loader.h>
#include <mach-o/dyld_images.h>
#include <mach-o/nlist.h>
#include <ptrauth.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#endif

#if defined(__APPLE__)
//Calls dlopen inside of a pthread in the remote target
auto remote_load_library = [](std::size_t* instructions_size) -> std::uint8_t* {
    static std::uint8_t assembly[] = {
        0xFD, 0x7B, 0xBD, 0xA9,    //stp x29, x30, [sp, #-48]!
        0xF5, 0x0B, 0x00, 0xF9,    //str x21, [sp, #16]
        0xF4, 0x4F, 0x02, 0xA9,    //stp x20, x19, [sp, #32]
        0xFD, 0x03, 0x00, 0x91,    //mov x29, sp
        0x02, 0x4C, 0x40, 0xA9,    //ldp x2, x19, [x0]           //_dlopen_pointer/_pthread_callback = data[0]
        0x08, 0x50, 0x41, 0xA9,    //ldp x8, x20, [x0, #16]      //_pthread_create_from_mach_thread = data[2]
        0x15, 0x10, 0x40, 0xF9,    //ldr x21, [x0, #32]          //_mach_thread_self = data[4]
        0xBF, 0x0F, 0x00, 0xF9,    //str xzr, [x29, #24]         //pthread_t thread_id = 0;
        0xE3, 0x03, 0x01, 0xAA,    //mov x3, x1                  //dll_path
        0xE1, 0x03, 0x1F, 0xAA,    //mov x1, xzr                 //nullptr
        0xA0, 0x63, 0x00, 0x91,    //add x0, x29, #24            //&thread_id
        0x00, 0x01, 0x3F, 0xD6,    //blr x8                      //_pthread_create_from_mach_thread(&thread_id, nullptr, _dlopen_pointer, dll_path)
        0xA0, 0x0F, 0x40, 0xF9,    //ldr x0, [x29, #24]          //thread_id
        0x60, 0x02, 0x3F, 0xD6,    //blr x19                     //_pthread_set_self(thread_id)
        0xA0, 0x02, 0x3F, 0xD6,    //blr x21                     //_mach_thread_self()
        0x80, 0x02, 0x3F, 0xD6,    //blr x20                     //_thread_suspend(_mach_thread_self())
        0xA0, 0x0F, 0x40, 0xF9,    //ldr x0, [x29, #24]          //return thread_id
        0xF4, 0x4F, 0x42, 0xA9,    //ldp x20, x19, [sp, #32]
        0xF5, 0x0B, 0x40, 0xF9,    //ldr x21, [sp, #16]
        0xFD, 0x7B, 0xC3, 0xA8,    //ldp x29, x30, [sp], #48
        0xC0, 0x03, 0x5F, 0xD6,    //ret

        0x1F, 0x20, 0x03, 0xD5,
        0x1F, 0x20, 0x03, 0xD5,
        0x1F, 0x20, 0x03, 0xD5,    //nop
        0x1F, 0x20, 0x03, 0xD5,
        0x1F, 0x20, 0x03, 0xD5,

        0x41, 0x00, 0x80, 0x52,    //mov w1, #2                  //RTLD_NOW = 0x02
        0xE2, 0xDD, 0x97, 0xD2,    //mov x2, #0xBEEF             //address of dlopen
        0xA2, 0xD5, 0xBB, 0xF2,    //movk x2, #0xDEAD, lsl #16   //address of dlopen
        0x02, 0x00, 0xD6, 0xF2,    //movk x2, #0xB000, lsl #32   //address of dlopen
        0x02, 0x00, 0xF4, 0xF2,    //movk x2, #0xA000, lsl #48   //address of dlopen
        0x40, 0x00, 0x1F, 0xD6,    //br x2                       //call dlopen(pthread_parameters, RTLD_LAZY)
    };
    
    //The above assembly is equal to:
    /*pthread_t LoadLibrary(void** data, void* dll_path)
     {
         void* (*_dlopen_pointer)(void* param) = data[0];
         void (*_pthread_set_self)(pthread_t thread) = data[1];
         int (*_pthread_create_from_mach_thread)(pthread_t *, const pthread_attr_t *, void *(*)(void *), void *) = data[2];
         kern_return_t (*_thread_suspend)(thread_read_t target_act) = data[3];
         mach_port_t (*_mach_thread_self)(void) = data[4];

         pthread_t thread_id = 0;
         _pthread_create_from_mach_thread(&thread_id, nullptr, _dlopen_pointer, dll_path);         
         _pthread_set_self(thread_id);
         _thread_suspend(_mach_thread_self());
         return thread_id;
     }

     void* _dlopen_pointer(void* param)
     {
         decltype(dlopen)* _dlopen = (decltype(dlopen)*)0xA000B000DEADBEEF;
         return _dlopen((const char*)param, RTLD_NOW);
     }*/

    *instructions_size = sizeof(assembly);
    return &assembly[0];
};

bool Injector::Inject(std::string module_path, std::int32_t pid, void* bootstrap) noexcept
{
    std::size_t assembly_size = 0;
    std::uint8_t* assembly = remote_load_library(&assembly_size);

    //Retrieve a task port for the remote process..
    mach_port_t    remote_task = 0;
    mach_error_t err = task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), pid, &remote_task);
    if (err == 5)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not access task for pid %d. You probably need to add user to procmod group OR run this program as root\n", pid);
        return false;
    }

    std::uint64_t stack_size = 16 * 1024;

    // Allocate and write the path size..
    mach_vm_address_t remote_path = reinterpret_cast<mach_vm_address_t>(nullptr);
    mach_vm_allocate(remote_task, &remote_path, module_path.size() + 1, VM_FLAGS_ANYWHERE);
    mach_vm_write(remote_task, remote_path, reinterpret_cast<mach_vm_offset_t>(module_path.c_str()), static_cast<mach_msg_type_number_t>(module_path.size()));
    mach_vm_protect(remote_task, remote_path, module_path.size() + 1, 0, VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_WRITE);

    //Update our dlopen address..
    void* dlopen_ptr = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "dlopen");
    
    // Bits 21 to 5 = imm of the MOV wide immediate instruction
    // https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0602/2023-03/Base-Instructions/MOV--wide-immediate---Move--wide-immediate---an-alias-of-MOVZ-?lang=en

    auto copy_bits = [](std::uint32_t &reg, std::uint16_t value) {
        for (int bit = 20, valueBit = 15; bit >= 5; --bit, --valueBit)
        {
            std::uint32_t bit_to_set = ((value >> valueBit) & 1);
            reg ^= (-bit_to_set ^ reg) & (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(1) << bit);
        }
    };
    
    // Convert the instruction bytes to 32-bit instruction
    auto decode_instruction = [](std::uint8_t instructions[]) -> std::uint32_t {
        //Note endianness
        return (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(instructions[3]) << 24) |
               (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(instructions[2]) << 16) |
               (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(instructions[1]) << 8) |
               (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(instructions[0]) << 0);
    };
    
    // Convert the 32-bit instruction back into instruction bytes
    auto encode_instruction = [](std::uint32_t instruction, std::uint8_t (&instructions)[4]) {
        //Note endianness
        instructions[3] = (instruction & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
        instructions[2] = (instruction & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
        instructions[1] = (instruction & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
        instructions[0] = (instruction & 0x000000FF) >> 0;
    };
    
    // Get the instructions offset, and write the address of dlopen to each part, 16-bits at a time
    auto write_instruction_address = [&](std::uint32_t address_intermediate, std::uint8_t assembly[], std::size_t offset) {
        std::uint8_t instructions[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
        memcpy(&instructions, &assembly[assembly_size + offset], sizeof(instructions));
        
        std::uint32_t instruction = decode_instruction(instructions);
        copy_bits(instruction, address_intermediate);
        encode_instruction(instruction, instructions);
        memcpy(&assembly[assembly_size + offset], &instructions, sizeof(instructions));
    };
    
    // Convert the dlopen address to its 16-bit parts
    std::uintptr_t dlopen_address = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(dlopen_ptr);
    std::uint32_t beef = ((dlopen_address & 0x000000000000FFFF) >> 0);
    std::uint32_t dead = ((dlopen_address & 0x00000000FFFF0000) >> 16);
    std::uint32_t b000 = ((dlopen_address & 0x0000FFFF00000000) >> 32);
    std::uint32_t a000 = ((dlopen_address & 0xFFFF000000000000) >> 48);
    
    // Write the encoded instructions back into the assembly payload
    // So it _dlopen_pointer will have the real address instead of 0xA000B000DEADBEEF
    write_instruction_address(a000, assembly, -8);
    write_instruction_address(b000, assembly, -12);
    write_instruction_address(dead, assembly, -16);
    write_instruction_address(beef, assembly, -20);

    //Allocate and write our remote code
    mach_vm_address_t remote_code = reinterpret_cast<mach_vm_address_t>(nullptr);
    mach_vm_allocate(remote_task, &remote_code, assembly_size, VM_FLAGS_ANYWHERE);
    mach_vm_write(remote_task, remote_code, reinterpret_cast<mach_vm_offset_t>(&assembly[0]), static_cast<mach_msg_type_number_t>(assembly_size));
    mach_vm_protect(remote_task, remote_code, assembly_size, false, VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_EXECUTE);

    //Allocate remote stack
    mach_vm_address_t remote_stack = reinterpret_cast<mach_vm_address_t>(nullptr);
    mach_vm_allocate(remote_task, &remote_stack, stack_size, VM_FLAGS_ANYWHERE);
    mach_vm_protect(remote_task, remote_stack, stack_size, true, VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_WRITE);

    //Allocate & write parameters
    void* parameters[] = {
        (void*)((remote_code + assembly_size) - 24),
        (void*)dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "_pthread_set_self"),
        (void*)dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "pthread_create_from_mach_thread"),
        (void*)dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "thread_suspend"),
        (void*)dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "mach_thread_self")
    };

    mach_vm_address_t remote_parameters = reinterpret_cast<mach_vm_address_t>(nullptr);
    mach_vm_allocate(remote_task, &remote_parameters, sizeof(parameters), VM_FLAGS_ANYWHERE);
    mach_vm_write(remote_task, remote_parameters, reinterpret_cast<mach_vm_offset_t>(&parameters[0]), static_cast<mach_msg_type_number_t>(sizeof(parameters)));

    //Offset stack pointer.
    mach_vm_address_t local_stack = remote_stack;
    remote_stack += (stack_size / 2);  //real stack location
    
    
    // To support ARMv7 and ARMv8, we use arm_unified_thread_state_t intead of arm_thread_state64_t
    arm_unified_thread_state_t state = {0};
    memset(&state, 0, sizeof(state));

    //Parameter order for aarch64: x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5
    state.ash.flavor = ARM_THREAD_STATE64;
    state.ash.count = ARM_THREAD_STATE64_COUNT;
    state.ts_64.__x[0] = remote_parameters; //pointers to functions
    state.ts_64.__x[1] = remote_path;       //path of module to load
    state.ts_64.__pc = (mach_vm_address_t)remote_code; //code/payload to execute
    state.ts_64.__sp = remote_stack;
    state.ts_64.__lr = 0x0000000000000000;  //Return address. Thread should suspend anyway.

    //Create our remote thread
    thread_act_t thread;
    err = thread_create_running(remote_task, ARM_THREAD_STATE64, (thread_state_t) &state.ts_64, ARM_THREAD_STATE64_COUNT, &thread);
    if (err != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR!\n");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
#endif

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    printf("Running\n");

    const char* dll_path = "/users/brandon/Desktop/test.dylib";
    Injector::Inject(dll_path, getpid(), nullptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas why I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when replacing `getpid()` in `main` with another process' PID?

Comment: Totally unrelated: It's weird seeing `arm_unified_thread_state_t state = {0};`, zero-initialize object, and `memset(&state, 0, sizeof(state));`, write zero to all storage used by object, both in use. Minor brainfart or is there a tactical reason to do this?

Comment: You really want to check the return values of your `mach_vm_blah` calls.

Comment: What is the target process?  Taking on board @mike's comment above, one of the many levels of security built into macOS might be thwarting you.

Comment: @MikeVine; I checked the return values. They all return `KERN_SUCCESS`. Only `return value (thread_id)` I cannot check in the injected process when it calls `_pthread_create_from_mach_thread` because it immediately gives the crash error. I tried setting a `brk #0` breakpoint but no luck reading the registers once I do.

Comment: @PaulSanders; I am injecting into a Test console application I wrote. I launch it with `./Test` in a terminal. The application just does `while(true) { sleep(1); }`

Comment: Ahh. Something weird is happening. If I run my Test process with Xcode, and inject into that test process, it works fine. If I run it with Terminal, it will NOT inject!

Comment: Do you have proof that your injected code is able to run at all (in the other process)?  If you have it do something much simpler, does it work?  Another good check would be for the injector program to print out the addresses of the various mappings so you can compare with where the crash occurs.

Comment: It looks like you're populating the remote parameters with pointers to the various library functions, as obtained by `dlsym` in the *injector* process.  How can we be sure that the library is going to be mapped at the same address in the target process?

Comment: @NateEldredge for stock libraries, that is actually going to be the case. The result of many special exceptions and "accelerations".

Comment: Something doesn't match up here. Where is `0x10005e85c` coming from? That address is too low to correspond to either shared libraries or your shellcode. This could only be either dyld or the main process binary, though the latter is a lot more likely. Is is faulting while trying to run instructions from there, or do the instructions there do something that causes a fault? How does it ever get there? Can you print all 5 addresses in `parameters`, and post the output of running `vmmap [otherpid]`, please?

Comment: @NateEldredge; You are 100% right. Was dumb on my part. On x86_64 (Intel based Macs), the address in the current process was the same across all the processes, and so the code worked fine. I assumed it'd be the same for ARM64, but I was wrong!!! I turns out, I had to parse the mach_header_64 of the target process, to find the symbols for dlopen, pthread_create_from_mach_thread, etc. Now it works!! It injects into any and every process just fine!

It's weird because when the target process is ran by Xcode, the address of everything is the same! But when ran normally, it is not :o

Comment: @Siguza; The address is a bad address. It's an address in the injector and not in the target process :( It was caused by me assuming the address of functions in the target and in the injector was the same. When I called `pthread_create_from_mach_thread`, it leaves the `thread` parameter undefined. That was the value of it when the function failed due to invalid parameters being passed.

Comment: This is the code now that works: https://gist.github.com/Brandon-T/76f0738b0ceced81dc50b00328bcb069
Line 61 and 107 is the new functions that find the symbols and libraries in the remote process, so I can inject the correct parameters. :)

Comment: That's really odd, the addresses should be the same, ever across different users... unless you were mixing process architectures?

Comment: @Siguza; I compiled the two applications myself. Both are compiled with `$(STANDARD_ARCHS)` on the same Mac Studio. I tried compiling both as arm64 instead of standard_archs, no difference. With `codesign -dvvv` I can see both are `arm64`. Yeah I found it very odd indeed. They should be the same across processes, but they were different unless I ran it both with Xcode. Running them standalone after archiving and exporting the built products, the addresses were different :S. BTW, Thank you for your sandbox escape writeup and iOS contributions! and for looking at my post :)

Comment: @Siguza: Maybe I don't know all the background, but I would think that mapping libraries at different addresses in different processes would be a natural part of ASLR.  That would also explain OP's observation that it didn't happen inside Xcode: it's common for debuggers to switch off ASLR to make things "easier" for the programmer.

Comment: @NateEldredge for "normal" libraries, that's what would happen. But stock libraries have all been merged into the "dyld shared cache", a >4GB file that gets put into a special shared memory region, mapped into processes as COW. This allows not just the text segment, but even a bunch of page tables to be shared across processes, as well as some pages that would only be modified by the linker and be made readonly thereafter (the kernel performs the "linking" on those at page-in these days).

Comment: @NateEldredge there can be multiple shared regions, and they're split between architecture, page size, file system root, and a few other criteria (DriverKit binaries get their own, for example), but beyond that, they're deduplicated. That is, the kernel looks for a compatible one before creating a new one. And ASLR is just applied the first time any shared region is mapped into. So if I look at the output of `vmmap` for a few different pids on my system, stock libraries are actually at the same addresses.